# Python # Pyinstaller build problem on using Text Fsm

Tags: python, pyinstaller, netmiko, python-textfsm

I made a simple program by using Python to access CISCO devices.
I am using the Netmiko Textfsm method for this. When I build an .exe using pyinstaller it works fine.
However, if I copy the .exe to another PC, it shows an error:

> Directory containing TextFSM index file not found.
>
> Please set the **NET_TEXTFSM** environment variable to point at the directory containing your TextFSM
> index file.
>
> Alternatively, `pip install ntc-templates` (if using ntc-templates).

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you need to use an absolute path and not a relative path here:

```
os.environ["NET_TEXTFSM"] = "lib/ntc-templates/templates"
```

os.path.join should use the absolute path as follows because relative paths are not supported here:

```
def get_structured_data(raw_output, platform, command):
            """Convert raw CLI output to structured data using TextFSM template."""
            template_dir = get_template_dir()
            index_file = os.path.join('/Users/barissonmez/ntc-templates/templates/', '/Users/barissonmez/ntc-templates/templates/index')
    '/Users/barissonmez/ntc-templates/templates/index'
            textfsm_obj = clitable.CliTable(index_file, template_dir)
```

Comment: Should i set etc-templates path everywhere, when i  using the .exe file in different PC? Is there have no option to build complete package of .exe without set the path repeatedly?